# Omnibug sometimes showing load events as click events?

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to understand why omnibug sometimes show load events as click events. When I first type in the URL all tags are listed as click events. If I reload the same page all the tags are shown as load events? Why the difference? I see this from time to time with omnibug, does anyone know what is actually defined as click events vs load events. Sometimes a load instead of a click can be a big issue, but Omnibug doesn't seem very reliable in this regard...

[image]

Comment: One of the Omnibug devs here, it's a known issue. The chrome plugin is in desperate need of an overhaul ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a known/reported bug in omnibug relevant to this. I heard through the grapevine it has to do with how the browser pre-fetches and/or caches requests. This also happens with Google/Universal Analytics entries.

For Adobe Analytics (Omniture), you can ensure it really is a click event (`s.tl` call) by expanding the row and looking for the following two items(should both be present):

**Link type**: This represents the 2nd argument to `s.tl()`, and is the `pe=` query param in the request URL. It should have one of these 3 values: "lnk_o","lnk_e", or "lnk_d".

**Link name**: This represents the 3rd argument to `s.tl()`, and is the `pev2=` query param in the request URL.

If these two things are not present, then it will be recorded as a page view request (`s.t()`) in Adobe Analytics (Omniture).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I see in omnibug "lnk_o" (or whatever link type is set to in s.tl() twice, i.e. Link type "lnk_o",
"lnk_o" - should I be worried?